# Does anyone know where to hire a car camper (not a campervan) in Australia?

Tags: driving, australia, camping, car-rentals, campers

I'm looking for somewhere to hire a car camper not a campervan.

For those who do not know what a car camper is, here's a description [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campervan):

> The car camper is a station wagon converted into a travel home.The rear cargo area is converted into a full double bed area usually with a fabricated aluminium framework. All equipment neccessary to set up a well appointed camp site is stored under the double bed with access through lidded areas under the bed. Unlike a standard station wagon where the camping equipment has to be removed before sleeping or a tent set up the car camper is self contained.

(A station wagon is known as an estate or shooting brake in some countries)

Comment: I'm Australian and I've never heard the term "car camper" before. Can you explain a bit what such a thing is?

Answer (score 6):

There are several online booking sites available that offer car campers in Australia. I'll list some of them:

- http://www.travellers-autobarn.com.au/car-rental-australia
- https://rentalcarmanager.com.au
- http://www.campertravel.com.au/
- [http://www.fly-to-australia.com/Camper_**4WD/body_camper**_4wd.html](http://www.fly-to-australia.com/Camper___4WD/body_camper___4wd.html)

I think with that you should have a broad selection of car campers in whole Austrlia.

Comment: Hmm all of those seem to be either regular station wagons or regular campervans. Only `campertravel.com.au` mentions "... and fully equipped station wagons Car rentals ..." - Buying a used normal station wagon is pretty normal for long term backpackers in Australia, and it's what I recommend usually. But they don't have the features of a car camper that Wikipedia mentions.

Comment: But what is the difference between regular station wagons and station wagons? I really don't understand it.

Comment: There is no difference between regular station wagons and station wagons. There is a difference between station wagons and car campers: "car camper is a station wagon converted into a travel home". A (regular) station wagon has not been converted. Doesn't have the fabricated aluminium framework for the double bed, etc.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [spaceship](http://www.spaceshipsrentals.com.au/). I know in New Zealand the locals aren't fond of these as they don't have a toilet on board and the occupants don't use discretion when it comes to choosing places to go to the toilet. I'm not sure about Australia but in New Zealand there are heavy fines for not cleaning up after oneself. Happy Camping.

Comment: geez, all the debate in the chat room last night about what a car camper is, and I could just have asked you on gtalk!

Comment: Personally I prefer a long wheelbase toyota hilux a little less room still sleeps two. But it will get you just about anywhere with out breaking a sweat. (possibly cheaper to hire, though you then need to buy your own cooker and foam squabs to sleep on)

Answer (score 3):

This category is also known as "Sleepervans"  Jucy Campers is another that use a combination of people movers like Toyota Previas outfitted with camping gear, bed and custom made awning extensions or even rooftop tents.

There are plenty of sleepervans and a few Camping Cars for both New Zealand and Australian rentals on [motorhomerepublic.com](http://www.motorhomerepublic.com), which I'm affiliated with.